# Add Relative Force not in direction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Attempting to create a 2D game where force is added to a RigidBody2D according to the rotation of the object.

The object is a projectile. Objects spawn at their intended rotation but only move right along the X axis instead according to the rotation.

Anyone know where I'm going wrong?

```cs
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    myRB = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    timer = Time.time + lifetime;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{

    myRB.AddRelativeForce(transform.right * thrust);

    if(Time.time > timer)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is about [tag:c#], not [tag:unityscript].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`transform.right`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-right.html) is already

> The red axis of the transform **in world space.**

with the orientation applied.

You are passing that in again as a Vector relative to the local space of the object which is not what you want.

Either use in world space

```
myRB.AddForce(transform.right * thrust);
```

or in local space

```
myRB.AddRelativeForce(Vector3.right * thrust);
```